# Configuración de reglas de seguridad - Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

Buenas noches a todos!

Realicé un e-commerce para un cliente, y decidí guardar sus productos (nombre, descripcion, precio, stock, etc) en una colección dentro de Firestore.
Al principio, tenia una regla de seguridad donde toda la data podia ser leida y modificada por cualquier persona, por lo cual firebase me avisaba una vez al dia que "Tu base de datos de Cloud Firestore contiene reglas que no son seguras".
Ahora las reglas estan configuradas asi:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == 'algunmail@gmail.com';
    }
  }
}
```

Ahora, leer la base lo puede hacer cualquiera, pero modificarla, solamente la persona que se autentique con el mail que ponga al final de la linea de "allow write: if...."

Aun asi, Firebase me envía el mismo mensaje "Tu base de datos de Cloud Firestore contiene reglas que no son seguras".

Entiendo que leer la base de datos tiene que estar asi, ya que si en "allow read: if..." pongo:

**false:** cualquiera que entre al dominio que consume esos datos, no los va a ver.

**autenticar para leer:** si pongo que solo los lea quienes se autentiquen, no tendria sentido el e-commerce segun entiendo, ya que, por ejemplo en Mercado Libre o la pagina de Fravega uno no tiene que registrarse para ver el precio y los productos publicados.

La explicacion del mail:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden dar una mano, les agradeceria.